# HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: vaadin

This is the piece of code i wrote and i was not able to solve this error in vaadin.

```
try{
    connectionPool=new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(driver,path,usuario,senha,2,5);
    TableQuery q1=new TableQuery("dispatch_list",connectionPool);
    q1.setVersionColumn("VERSION");
    SQLContainer DispatchContainer=new SQLContainer(q1);
    table.setContainerDataSource(DispatchContainer);
} catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
table.setWidth("100%");
return table;
```

And exception I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:java.lang.AbstractMethodError
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
root cause

com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:java.lang.AbstractMethodError
com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1440)
        com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1394)
        com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
root cause
```

Answer (score 0):

The best guess could be this:
You may not have copied the Database Driver jar file into the Servlet-Container's (ie, Tomcat's LIB folder). If you have not done that then, do that, restart the container, and let me know if everything is alright.

Comment: Is it the mysql-connector you mean when you say database driver?.if so i have it in the ivy dependencies.i also have doubts on would SQLContainer addon works with vaadin 7 with out issue?can please share me that information.

Comment: I have not personally used SQL Container, as I am against putting the database/business related stuff in Web UI tier directly.